# Facebook url does not work

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to do a Facebook Application but when I access my URL app:

https://apps.facebook.com/420842188090395

Don't show my application and when I access my direct url it give me my token and works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you app settings turn on in facebook?

Comment: Yes!
When I acess my URL directly works fine, authenticates the user and give me informations of this user.

Comment: Its hard to say what the problem is. You need to post more information.

Comment: Now It's working. The problem was SSL.

Comment: Can you please add your solution as an answer to this question and accept your own answer. This will help people who may come across this issue in the future.

Comment: I only installed SSL in my server